# Reserve-Step Algorithm / Anti-Banding Algorithm for Terrain?

Tags: algorithm, reverse, smoothing, terrain, heightmap

I took the data from [here (Nasa - Topography)](https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/images/73934/topography) and [here (Nasa - Bathymetric)](https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/images/73963/bathymetry) and used it to create a 3D model of the Earth's entire surface (both above and below water).

Here's what I got:
[image: Jadded Heightmap]
As you can see, it is super jagged.

The problem is that due to the fact that I'm using *greyscale* images, I only have 512 distinct levels to work with (256*2). When going from the ocean floor to the highest peak, you're obviously going to hit more than 512 distinct elevations. So it's basically an [unwanted step-function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIlGw.jpg).
Had they used all RGB channels this wouldn't be a problem, but then the image wouldn't be very "human-readable"

Smoothing in general is a possibility, but not a great possibility because it will lower the quality of cliffs, peaks, canyons, ect. drastically.

**Here's the thing:** we know that each pixel is within (maxHeight-minHeight)/512 (**=maxoffset**) of the actually correct value: as stated it has pretty much gone through an unwanted step function. Of course, [mathematically a step function is irreversible](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-inverse-of-a-step-function) - however, that doesn't stop us from trying!

Here are some of my thoughts on how this might work:

- Find the average height of surrounding pixels, for some radius. Calculate the difference between this pixel's current value and the calculated average. Do nothing with this value yet.
- While calculating this, store which pixel has the greatest difference.
- Then, "normalize" all values such that this greatest difference is *(maxHeight-minHeight)/512*: the **maxoffset**: the max that a pixel could be off. Due to outliers, this "normalization" shouldn't be linear, but such that the average is 85% (or something) of this maxoffset.
- Peaks (pixels that are higher than all surrounding pixels) and Basins (same idea except lower) get excluded from this process, as they'll be outliers and shouldn't change much anyhow (or undergo a process of their own).

That might not work. I could still use basic "average smoothing" except with the following rules:

- No smoothing of peaks (pixels that are higher than all surrounding pixels), basins (same idea except lower), cliffs (this is way more difficult and may not happen - but the idea is to check if pixels have a drop on one side and roughly the same height pixels on the other side for some distance).
- If the pixel has significantly more pixels around the same height than not, give greater weight to those nearly-same-height pixels.

I'm also looking into finding better "data", but I'm not confident that I will due to the fact that I require bathymetric data: most GPS APIs are Topography exclusive. In any case, this is an interesting problem nonetheless and I'm curious if are already some good algorithms.

Comment: hmm I would try to use difference between sliding average and raw data to detect slopes (if you are on slope the difference would be much smaller)... then smooth the slopes areas only ... Also I would separate this to single axis ... and process all of them separately. The edges of slopes can be smoothed with smaller and smaller weights as they get closer to edge itself so the mesh will join smoothly....

Comment: There are several image formats that don't require discrete levels (for example tiff: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF) Unless you have a compelling reason to discretize your data, the answer is: don't. For this reason, geospatial data is usually shipped in geotiff format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoTIFF . You should be able to find the same data you are working with in geotiff format.

Comment: I just realized: the data Nasa provided here is Tiff, but they only used 8 bits per pixel! How frusterating!

Comment: If NASA discretized the data they may have had a compelling reason for it (most older satellites have a very limited download link capability & require compressed data.) I would suggest looking for more recent data, these types of limitations are only true of older data where satellites were much more limited in their resolution/capabilities. It may be that higher resolution data requires payment however (unfortunate!)

Comment: If you are an advanced user of geospatial data, you can form your own DEMs using somewhat raw (but most importantly free!) sensor data. See for example how to do it using Sentinel 1 SAR (InSAR) data: https://asf.alaska.edu/how-to/data-recipes/create-a-dem-using-sentinel-1-data/

Note, the quality of your DEM may be largely unknown if you create it yourself, however.